# usage of the return value of scanf

Tags: c, scanf

I am learning C from a book and I am starting  with loop instructions. But there is a sample code which I could not understand.

Can anyone tell me why author has used `status = scanf("%ld", &num);` ? Why there is a `=` with `scanf` ?

```
/* summing.c -- sums integers entered interactively */
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    long num;
    long sum = 0L; /* initialize sum to zero */
    int status;      
    printf("Please enter an integer to be summed ");
    printf("(q to quit): ");
    status = scanf("%ld", &num);
    while (status == 1) /* == means "is equal to" */
    {
        sum = sum + num;
        printf("Please enter next integer (q to quit): ");
        status = scanf("%ld", &num);
    }
    printf("Those integers sum to %ld.\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Because `scanf()` returns a value indicating how well the string matched the format passed, i.e. how many parameters were successfuly filled with data.

You would know that if your read some kind of [manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) page, or the standard, if you ever encounter a function that you don't know, always read about it as much as you can, so you can understand how to use it.

Answer (score 5):

`scanf` returns the number of successfully matched items from its specifier list. So, if you enter "q", `scanf` will return 0 (since "q" is not an integer), and the loop will terminate.

Answer (score 5):

Please have a look at the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) of `scanf()`. It returns the number of items *successfully* scanned. So the return value is used to check the successfulness of `scanf()`.

In your code,

```
 status = scanf("%ld", &num);
 // code
 while (status == 1)
```

the return value of `scanf()` is stored into `status` and checked later to check whether `scanf()` has successfully scanned `1` item or not.

- If it has returned `1`, meaning a `long int` has been entered. Then the `while()` loop will continue, asking for the next input.
- One you enter `q`, it won't match the coversion specifier `%ld`, hence `scanf()` will fail, hence it will return `0`. Then the `while()` loop will terminate.